# Visual FoxPro connection driver

Tags: driver, visual-foxpro, dbf

Actually i want to connect power bi with a visualfoxpro database, but the odbc driver for vfp is only for 32 bits, I can't find a free odbc driver for connect with the vfp, anyone has one? thanks

the dowload link or documentation for connect with a .dbc vfp or .dbf tables

Comment: `the odbc driver for vfp is only for 32 bits` FoxPro is also 32 bits only, so you won't have a problem with this.

Comment: Since VFP6 there is no official ODBC driver. There is only OLEDB driver (VFPOLEDB) and it is 32 bits. If your Power BI is 32 bits then you could use VFPOLEDB to connect. Otherwise I am afraid you need to find an unofficial ODBC\OLEDB driver. You might check sybase driver but AFAIK it is paid.